# MODX Revolution MIGX filter TV by date

Tags: modx, migx

I'm using MODX Revolution MIGX for a variety of TVs that are displayed in a table via getImageList. I need to filter the results by a date TV to all future dates.

Anyone knows?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `&where` clause to your MIGX call and use a snippet to get today's date in a suitable format.

```
<?php
/*
* Today's date snippet, save as TodaysDate
*/
return date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Example where clause:

```
[[getImageList?
    &tvname=`my_tv`
    &tpl=`my_tpl`
    &where=`{"my_date:<=":"[[TodaysDate]]"}`
]]
```